# R: find missing data and add it with a zero

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following set of data:

[image]

The rows in Yellow is an example of a good situation, because for Vaer=B both Var2=F and Var2=G a freq value is present.

But, rows in red are example of a bad situation, because row 13 where Var2=F have freq value at date 07.02.2018 but I do not have a value for Var2=G at the same date.

On the other hand, row 27 in red, I have freq value for Var2=G at date 04:02:2018 but I do not have freq value for Var2=F at the same date.

**What I need is:**
For all type of Var1 (A, B, ..) and For each Var2 (F, G) If freq is present in Var2=F but not in Var2=G create for Var2=G freq=0 at the same date.

The same have to be mabe for Var2=G where Var2=F is not present.

Could you give me some idea how to do that in R?

Comment: Please don't provide data as an image!! Read [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is a bit cryptic to me, but I guess you have counts for all groups but you need to have them as well for all permutations, even if there are no observations (therefore fill `freq` with 0). You can use `tidyr::complete`:

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                 Var2 = c("F", "G", "F", "G", "F"),
                 freq = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L),
                 date = as.Date(c("2018-04-27", "2018-04-28", "2018-04-27", "2018-04-28", "2018-04-29")))
tidyr::complete(data = df, Var1, Var2, date, fill = list(freq = 0L))
```

Comment: Hi Tino, really thanks. I have to start to study a bit od tidyr.

Comment: Just another question: considering the same problem using the df your created, is it possible to have all permutation but separately for Var1=A and Var2=B?

Comment: You could use `subset()` like `subset(df, Var1=="A" & Var2=="B")`.

Comment: of course, thank you!